# Get Header Request Javascript: cURL working, fetch forbidden

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, get, request

i want to GET Request the Header of this link  https://soundcloud.app.goo.gl/u6XXuqp3Q7Q7WXgH8 in a React App. When doing a simple request

```
 request('https://soundcloud.app.goo.gl/u6XXuqp3Q7Q7WXgH8', function (error, response, body) {
    console.error('error:', error); 
    console.log('body:', body);
        });
```

I get

```
Access to fetch at 'https://soundcloud.app.goo.gl/u6XXuqp3Q7Q7WXgH8' from 
origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-
Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an 
opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to 
fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

When using the cors-anywhere proxy

```
 request('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://soundcloud.app.goo.gl/u6XXuqp3Q7Q7WXgH8', function (error, response, body) {
    console.error('error:', error); 
    console.log('body:', body);
     });
```

I get

```
request.js:150 GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://soundcloud.app.goo.gl/u6XXuqp3Q7Q7WXgH8 403 (Forbidden)
```

But when I just cURL I get the right response

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -D -  https://soundcloud.app.goo.gl/u6XXuqp3Q7Q7WXgH8
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me and maybe tell me how to overcome this?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a CORS issue here, your clients domain needs to be whitelisted in your server or, if it already is, you need to correct your request headers.

Comment: The point is, I don't have access to the soundcloud servers. And using the cors-anywhere proxy is working for every other website except the soundcloud link :(

Comment: I also ran the application on an express server using the ´cors´ module and everything, but nothing works :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CORS error usually comes up when you are trying to call an API from your browser directly and that API doesn't allow any other website to get the data.

There can be 2 workarounds to this problem I can think as of now -

1. Either you call that API from your backend code and you gather the data received from the website in backend and transfer the data on the client-side. Basically, you will be Wrapping the original API.
2. You can use Web Servers like NGINX and configure a specific path on the domain pointing to External API and other paths to your project. Which will help in making both the External API and Your React code on the same domain name.

Mainly your objective is to have that external API to work through your domain working along with your react code.

Comment: yeah you're right...i just thought there might be solutions such as a special type of api request that won't be blocked by any cors stuff..

Answer (score 1):

In browser context JS, such as a in a fetch call to an API, CORS applies. Rather with a CURL request, you are essentially running server side context, therefore CORS doesn't apply. This is why you can hit instagrams unofficial api from a server context or node.js context, but not from the same fetch call in a browser. Possible solutions:

1. Allow-Content-Orgin header set by the server must include the domain your page is hosted on.
2. Use Eletron or NodeWebkit.js for visual apps running client side with a browser (chromium) to launch your app in (mix of both browser and server context, CORS does not apply)
3. Run a node.js app (no browser, server context) and run your app from the terminal. (CORS does not apply)